# Как проще всего сделать графический интерфейс windows rust новичку?

Tags: windows, интерфейс, rust

Я хочу сделать программу с графическим интерфейсом, информации маловато в интернете. Я хотел бы спросить какая библиотека самая простая для разработки приложений с графическим интерфейсом? (Я смотрел в сторону fltk или gtk-rs но они мне показались слишком сложными.)

Comment: Не встречал визуальных редакторов для построения ui для раста. Для выбора подходящей библиотеки можно ориентироваться на количество звёзд на гитхабе. Например вот ресурс с подборкой https://www.libhunt.com/l/rust/topic/gui